# Error "redirect_uri_mismatch" when trying to exchange authorization code for access token in Google API

Tags: google-oauth

As the title suggests, I am getting "redirect_uri_mismatch" when trying to exchange authorization code for access token in Google API (this is offline_access flow). However, the strange thing is, exact same code with same parameters works in one environment (staging) and doesn't work on another one (production). Logging shows that bodies of requests are exactly same (except the authorization code obviously).
Body is as follows:

```
{
    "client_id": "*client id*",
    "client_secret": "*client secret*",
    "code": "*authorization code*",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "redirect_uri": "*front-end url, registered in Google cloud console*"
}
```

Comment: The redirect uri 's you have in the google developer console needs to exactly match the ones that you are sending from.  my guess is you didnt add the production location.

Comment: If I use the offline access flow and retrieve the authorization code from different (frontend) uri, while I send this request from server, should I use frontend or server uri as redirect uri?

Comment: The redirect uril is the location that the authorization is returned to. You should add the server that can handle the call.  But if you are using one of the client libraries they are coded to use their current host.

Answer (score 1):

The `redirect_uri` is the location that the user will be redirected to after authorization.

The `redirect_uri` is where you are passed the `code` in the `GET` query parameters. @DalmTo describes this better as "redirect_uri is the location that the Authorization code is returned to it should be the code that can handle the authorization code exchange."

The `redirect_uri` must match one of the values stored in the Google Cloud API Console. This is a security measure to prevent someone from forging an authorization request that redirected the user to a different server. The `code` is the secret that is exchanged for OAuth 2 tokens.

The solution is to log in to the Google Cloud API console and add the `redirect_uri` for your production environment OR use the correct value in your request body that is already stored in the API Console.

Comment: redirect_uri is the location that the Authorization code is returned to it should be the code that can handle the authorization code exchange.

Comment: @DaImTo I like your description better so I added your words to my answer.

Comment: The request I provided is not one to get the authorization code, that one works just fine. It is the one to get access token from authorization code. This request is POST and it returns token as a response.

As for the solution, redirect_uri that I use is already added to Google console, evident by the fact that it works on dev environment, however, the same value does not work for production.

Do you know if there are any limitations of redirect uri for this request and the one from which the authorization code was obtained? Maybe they have to come from the same domain or something?